# Transfer from a NRE account to Ordinary Account

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, non-resident

Suppose I transfer a amount from my Aunts NRE account to my Bank account India.

I then repay this amount to my Aunt in her US bank account after a period of 2 months. I will show this either as a gift or some other way. Would there be any tax liabilities to her or to me in the US.

Can she transfer this amount from her US account into her NRE Account in India again.

Comment: _You_ cannot transfer money from your Aunt's NRE account unless you have signature authority over your aunt's account. Also, how much money are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

> Can she transfer this amount from her US account into her NRE Account in India again.

Yes. There is nothing stopping it.

> Suppose I transfer a amount from my Aunts NRE account to my Bank account India.

An NRI can [lend to another NRI](https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/ECMUserParaDetail.aspx?Id=525&CatID=14)

> (ii) Authorised dealers may allow transfer of funds between NRE accounts of different persons held with themselves or different authorised dealers for any purpose. Where the transfer of funds is by way of gift, it may be allowed after obtaining an undertaking from the transferee/transferee's banks that gift tax, if any, payable on the transfer of funds will be paid to the Income-tax authorities in India. In case of transfer of funds between NRE accounts held with different authorised dealers, the authorised dealer transferring the funds should issue a certificate confirming the non-resident status of the transferor.

Q

> I will show this either as a gift or some other way. Would there be any tax liabilities to her or to me in the US.

This would depend on what this is shown as.